# What is the keyboard shortcut to toggle fullscreen in OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mountain-lion, osx-spaces

If I have a window on my desktop in OSX Mountain Lion, I see an icon in the top right corner o the window, made of two diagonal arrows pointing away from each other. I can click this to put the app in "full screen" mode and give it its own space.

Once I've done that, I can hover my mouse near the top edge of the screen and the menu bar will slide down. There's a blue icon on the far right that looks like the opposite of the first: two diagonal arrows pointing toward each other. That will take the app out of full screen mode.

I'm being so specific because I want to be clear about which "fullscreen mode" I mean.

**What is the universal keyboard shortcut to toggle fullscreen mode in Mountain Lion?**

I'm aware of a few application-specific shortcuts, but they're inconsistent.

- In Google Chrome, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> toggles fullscreen, and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> toggles "presentation mode", which is the same but without showing the tabs.
- In Firefox, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> toggles fullscreen.
- In iTerm2, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> toggles fullscreen.

I'm looking for something universal, like how <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> minimizes the window for any app.

Answer (score 14):

You can try [this tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/10/full-screen-keyboard-shortcut-mac-os-x/).

> **IMPORTANT NOTE**: for me it's not working with the shortcut ***Command+Escape*** as suggested by this tutorial, but it is working with ***Command+Shift+F***, for
> example...

### STEPS:

- Open ***System Preferences*** and click on the ***Keyboard*** icon
- Select the ***Keyboard Shortcuts*** tab and choose ***Application Shortcuts*** from the list on the left
- Click on the ***+*** icon to add a new keyboard shortcut for all applications and type the following exactly:

> Enter Full Screen

- Now you need to assign it a keyboard shortcut, I chose ***Command+Escape*** because it serves no purpose in OS X, but it’s the old keyboard shortcut for entering into Front Row
- Click ***Add*** and then click on the ***+*** icon again, this time typing:

> Exit Full Screen

- Choose the same keyboard shortcut as you chose before, in this case ***Command+Escape***, and click onto **Add** again
- Close out ***System Preferences***
- Give it a try!

[image]

Comment: Works for me! Caveats: This is based on matching the **name** of the menu item. Eg, in iTerm2, it's "Toggle Full Screen", so I had to add another one with that name for it. Also, Firefox didn't respond to the new mapping, so I tried giving all apps its mapping of Command+Control+F, and that worked for me (at least for the three I mentioned and for MacVim, which calls its menu item "Toggle Full Screen **Mode**").

Comment: Waiting to accept in case there's a native way that someone can point out.

Comment: @NathanLong what kind of "native way" were you expecting? If apps are not following convention, this is how you can override the keyboard shortcut. How is this not "native"? I see you want something "universal" - this solution is universal.

Comment: @JBallin in KDE (Linux) for example it is possible to set a wide range of global shortcuts including "minimize", "close" and "full screen" for all Applications. It is somewhat disappointing how few shortcuts you can set/configure system-wide in MAC. Matching names in the menu is definitely not the cleanest possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Mavericks, and MikO's method didn't work for me, at least not in Terminal, which was how I came to this post. [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/), on the other hand, completely works, and, in fact, has a "Enter Fullscreen" action. Also, it's awesome.

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to what you tried? Screenshots of your keyboard shortcuts config would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used a Mac in like 5 years! Also, looks like BTT isn't actively developed anymore. I recommend switching to Linux!